# Aplicación en React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Necesito de vuestra ayuda, estoy realizando una aplicación que consulta a una API de Clima, es bastante sencilla y esta basada en un curso, la única diferencia es que estoy usando Yarn y Expo porque debo integrarla a otra aplicación. Luce así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente me tira 2 errores, cuando quiero seleccionar el país me dice "guardarBusqueda" is not a function" ver en la imagen siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El otro error lo hace al hacer click en buscar cuando no se ha definido ciudad, ya que es un requerimiento que este campo no este vacío: "pais is undefined". ver la imagen siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El Código esta tal cual el curso y no encuentro el error (estoy empezando con React-Native).
El Código es el siguiente:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {StyleSheet,Text, View,TextInput, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Animated, Alert} from "react-native";
import {Picker} from '@react-native-picker/picker'

const Formulario = ( busqueda, guardarBusqueda) => {

    const {pais, ciudad} = busqueda;

    const [animacionboton] = useState(new Animated.Value(1));

    const consultarClima = () => {
        if(pais.trim() === '' || ciudad.trim() === ''){
            mostrarAlerta();
            return;
        }

    }

    const mostrarAlerta = () => {
        Alert.alert(
            'Error',
            'Agrega una ciudad y país para la búsqueda',
            [{ text: ' Entendido '}]
        )
    }

    const animacionEntrada = () => {
        Animated.spring(animacionboton,{
            toValue: .75,
            useNativeDriver: true
        }).start();
    }
    const animacionSalida = () => {
        Animated.spring(animacionboton,{
            toValue: 1,
            friction: 2,
            tension: 30,
            useNativeDriver: true
        }).start();
    }
    
    const estiloAnimacion = {
        transform:[{scale: animacionboton}]
    }

    return(
        <>
            <View style={styles.formulario}>
                <View>
                    <TextInput
                        value={ciudad}
                        style={styles.input}
                        onChangeText={ ciudad => guardarBusqueda({ ...busqueda, ciudad}) }
                        placeholder="Ciudad"
                        placeholderTextColor="#666"
                    />
                    

                </View>
                <View>
                    <Picker
                        selectedValue={pais}
                        itemStyle={{height: 120, backgroundColor:'#FFF'}}
                        onValueChange={ pais => guardarBusqueda({ ...busqueda, pais}) }
                    >
                        <Picker.Item label="-- Seleccione un país --" value="" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Estados Unidos" value="US" />
                        <Picker.Item label="México" value="MX" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Argentina" value="AR" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Colombia" value="CO" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Costa Rica" value="CR" />
                        <Picker.Item label="España" value="ES" />
                        <Picker.Item label="Peru" value="PE" />
                    </Picker>
                </View>
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                    onPressIn={() => animacionEntrada() }
                    onPressOut={() => animacionSalida() }
                    onPress={ () => consultarClima() }
                
                >
                    <Animated.View
                        style={[ styles.btnBuscar, estiloAnimacion ]}
                    >
                        <Text
                            style={styles.textoBuscar}
                        >
                            Buscar Clima
                        </Text>
                    </Animated.View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            </View>


        </>

    );
}

})
export default Formulario;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recuerda que todos los componentes reciben props y para acceder a ellos debes hacer destructuring así:

```
const Formulario = ( {busqueda, guardarBusqueda} ) => {
 return (
  
 )
}
```

o así

```
const Formulario = ( props ) => {
 const { busqueda, guardarBusqueda } = props;
return (
)
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! venía por ahí la mano!
En el inicio de Formulario había puesto 
const Formulario = ( busqueda, guardarBusqueda) sin las llaves.
lo cambie a:
const Formulario = ( {busqueda, guardarBusqueda}) con llaves y salió funcionando.